# Width of 100% produces a scroll bar sized gap to the right of the layout off screen

Tags: html, css, layout

So I have a layout that I'm trying to make span 100% of the viewport width. Setting `width: 100%;` on the site's container element works exactly as expected - the width of the entire layout, indeed, the entire DOM structure even up to the `html` element, is 100% (in this case, 1425px on a 1440px wide screen, accounting for the 15px scrollbar). But for some reason, there is a 15px gap to the right of the layout off screen, which produces a horizontal scroll bar that shouldn't be there.

I've checked thoroughly and there is no element that is more than 1425px wide. Nothing has a `margin-right` or `padding-right` setting that could possibly push the content of the page. And as far as all my rendered content knows, the width of the render is 1425px - as I said, the `html` element is 1425px wide. For good measure I've tried setting all of the containing elements to `width: 100%;` to no avail. Setting `overflow-x` to hidden doesn't work because technically nothing is overflowing - all the content of the page fits with in the viewport. There's just some random whitespace being rendered out of thin air to the right of all the content.

I have absolutely no idea what could possibly be causing this gap, because it is off screen and not caused by any margin or padding. This behavior is consistent across all browsers.

Has anyone ever run into anything like this before?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body class="collection-type-page view-list mobile-style-available collection-53377421e4b0e7e398eacb73 collection-layout-default underline-body-links blog-meta-data-split  hide-author  social-icon-style-round gallery-design-grid aspect-ratio-auto lightbox-style-light gallery-navigation-circles gallery-info-overlay-show-on-hover gallery-aspect-ratio-32-standard gallery-arrow-style-circular gallery-transitions-fade gallery-show-arrows gallery-auto-crop  gallery-loop product-list-titles-under product-list-alignment-center product-item-size-11-square product-image-auto-crop product-gallery-size-11-square product-gallery-auto-crop show-product-price show-product-item-nav product-social-sharing   event-thumbnails event-thumbnail-size-32-standard event-date-label event-date-label-time event-excerpts event-list-date event-list-time event-list-address event-icalgcal-links      opentable-style-light newsletter-style-dark small-button-style-solid small-button-shape-square medium-button-style-solid medium-button-shape-square large-button-style-solid large-button-shape-square button-style-outline button-corner-style-rounded native-currency-code-usd" id="collection-53377421e4b0e7e398eacb73">

  <div id="site">
    <div id="canvas">

      <div id="headerWrapper">
        <header id="header">

          <div id="headerInfo" data-content-field="site-title">

            <h1 class="logo site-title">
              <a href="/" title="Title" role="bookmark">
                <span class="placed-site-title">Title</span>
              </a>
            </h1>
            <p class="site-tagline">Tagline</p>


            <div id="navBlock" role="navigation">

              <nav class="main-nav">

                <ul>
                      <li class="page-collection">
                        <a href="/">Link 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="page-collection active-link">
                        <a href="/bio/">Link 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="page-collection">
                        <a href="/works/">Link 3</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="blog-collection">
                        <a href="/blog/">Link</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="page-collection">
                        <a href="/connect/">Link</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="page-collection">
                        <a href="/colophon/">Link</a>
                      </li>
                </ul>

              </nav>


            </div>
          </div>

        </header>
      </div><!-- / headerWrapper -->

      <div id="pageWrapper" class="hfeed" role="main">
        <section id="page">
          <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12" data-type="page" data-updated-on="1401681420237" id="page-53377421e4b0e7e398eacb73"><div class="row sqs-row"><div class="col sqs-col-4 span-4"><div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image" data-aspect-ratio="176.11940298507463" data-block-type="5" id="block-yui_3_10_1_1_1398741322418_29922"><div class="sqs-block-content">

</div></div></div><div class="col sqs-col-8 span-8"><div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_10_1_1_1401672930436_6680"><div class="sqs-block-content">
<h2>Short Bio</h2>
<p>Bio here</p></div></div><div class="sqs-block horizontalrule-block sqs-block-horizontalrule" data-block-type="47" id="block-yui_3_10_1_1_1401672930436_6398"><div class="sqs-block-content"><hr /></div></div><div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_10_1_1_1401672930436_7764"><div class="sqs-block-content">
<h2>Long Bio</h2>
<p>Bio here</p></div></div></div></div></div>
        </section>
      </div><!-- / pageWrapper -->

      <div id="footerWrapper">
        <footer id="footer">


          <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12" data-layout-label="Footer" data-type="block-field" data-updated-on="1398747302443" id="footerBlock"><div class="row sqs-row"><div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12"><div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_10_1_1_1398744171225_2855"><div class="sqs-block-content"><p class="text-align-center"><a href="/colophon">Copyright Here</a></p></div></div></div></div></div>
        </footer>
      </div><!-- / footerWrapper -->

    </div><!-- / canvas -->
  </div><!-- / site -->

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS (computed):

```
html {
  -webkit-locale: en-US;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 1448.390625px;
  width: 1425px;
}

body {
  -webkit-background-size: auto;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  display: block;
  font-family: proxima-nova;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 1448.390625px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 27.200000762939453px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 1425px;
}

#site { /* main container */
  color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  display: block;
  font-family: proxima-nova;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 1448.390625px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 27.200000762939453px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 1425px;
}

#canvas { 
  color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  display: block;
  font-family: proxima-nova;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 1448.390625px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 27.200000762939453px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 1425px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can for this problem - I'm customizing a Squarespace template. This would actually be a lot easier to solve if I were starting from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's pretty difficult for us to test unless we can see some code. If you can give us anything we will probably be able to help.

Comment: Added as much code as I could given the situation.